# Connector identification - 2-pin miniature square, keyed, used on Bosch ebike

Tags: identification, connector

If anyone recognise these connectors can you give a make / series name? They're like automotive connectors but miniature - about 5 mm square. I've failed to find them on an extensive web search.

[image: connector photo 1]

[image: connector photo 2]

Many thanks.

Comment: Can't see anything exactly the same. But perhaps you can replace both sides. There are ignition plug connectors on amazon, with crimps.

Comment: What does the receptacle look like?

Comment: Automotive connectors are hard to identify. To identify automotive connectors, I use these folks: https://connectorexperts.com/. I also recommend checking with the parts department at the dealer for that brand of vehicle.

Comment: Thank you, @DavideAndrea. That's a great site - although after 19 pages of 2-pin connectors I can't help wondering how we can possibly need so many different connectors! I didn't find mine so I'm still looking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've already found an alternate solution, but for anyone this might help in the future, it looks like they're from a series of 'nano' automotive connectors made by TE Connectivity -
https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2141467-2.html